# Adding a parameter to the post-logout redirect

Tags: identityserver4

We're using IdentityServer4 for access control to a .net core 3 MVC application (we'll be adding a single page application later as well) where we've got a unique identifier as a parameter for the initial login page. 
How can we get the the post logout redirect to get back to the login page with the parameter from the previous login?
Thanks

Comment: In your login controller or application middleware set a cookie which stores the intermediate data. This kind of data is usually referred to as flash data in a web application. Once the logout request is complete, use the flash data to send them where they need to go. I'm not familiar with identity server 4 but 'm sure that's something you can easily implement in .net.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the identifier? What is exactly identified by it and am I correct that it's not supposed to change?